# Launch Win8.1 Store App with msApplication-Arguments

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Has anyone successfully used the msApplication-Arguments meta tag to launch a Win8.1 Store app with arguments? Once I add the msApplication-Arguments meta tag to my HTML code, my app fails to launch from the IE Store app.

Here is the MSDN documentation for launching a Store app from a web site via IE Store app. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781489.aspx

Here are my meta tags without my actual app ID and package name.

```
<meta name="msApplication-ID" content="myAppId" />
<meta name="msApplication-PackageFamilyName"
  content="myMicrosoftAppBuildPackageName" />
<meta name="msApplication-Arguments" content="myArgs" />
```

Comment: You can include query parameters in your launch protocol Uri which can be passed in and parsed (in the `OnProtocolActivated` event). Have you tried using those?

Comment: @Nate How can I pass in the Uri to the app? The app is launched from an IE app bar menu item. The msApplication-Arguments meta tag is supposed to do this. I already have 'OnProtocolActivated', and it works when the app is launched using '[protocol name]:///?[args]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue...msApplication-Arguments meta tag does not work from a static HTML file. If the HTML is run from a web server, everything works as described by the MSDN documentation.